# Git on OSX hangs on each command: How to fix it?

Tags: git

I am running mac osx lion.

My problem is that git hangs after I type in each command.

If i type in `git` then I get `Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>`

When I try to type in something else, for example `git status` the terminal just hangs, but once I hit enter again, then it goes back to the normal terminal prompt, but the command never goes through.

How do I get git to work?

Comment: That's odd output and behavior for git. Can you do this: `which git` ?

Comment: Where did you install it from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems with your specific approach to installing git, you might want to follow these instructions:
https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

```
# Test for the cred helper
git credential-osxkeychain

# Download the helper
curl -s -O \
  http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain

# Fix the permissions on the file so it can be run
chmod u+x git-credential-osxkeychain

# Now you need to install the helper into the 
# same directory where Git itself is installed.

# Find where git is installed
which git

# Move the file to the path `which git` returned so git can access it
sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/local/git/bin/

# Set git to use the osxkeychain credential helper
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

Personally, I just use [`homebrew`](https://brew.sh/) and its as easy as `brew install git`

Comment: When I do `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain` it still hangs.

Comment: I just installed it and then reinstalled it, which worked. :) I'm gonna accept this since you took the time to answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out! Sorry that I couldn't take you all the way through the process. It had to be something strange like that, where something didn't get installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I believe Jdi's answer is out-dated as it did NOT work for me.

My solution was to reinstall git

```
brew uninstall git
brew install git
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
git push
```

Git prompt me for a username & password which I entered. To check it worked I ran git push again and it did not ask for my credentials, all is good with the world again :).