# git push stops and no error message appeares

Tags: macos, git

I am using git on Mac OSX.

Suddenly I cant upload the repository by git push .

It stops in the way and shows no error message.

This is my trace.

I think it is related to mac osx keychain. does anyone help?

> GIT_TRACE=1 git pull origin ukehodai

```
trace: exec: 'git-pull' 'origin' 'ukehodai'
trace: run_command: 'git-pull' 'origin' 'ukehodai'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '-u'
trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'branch.ukehodai.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'pull.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok' 'origin' 'ukehodai'
trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/daichihaji/muty.git'
trace: run_command: 'git credential-osxkeychain get'
trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'git credential-osxkeychain get' 'git credential-osxkeychain get'
trace: exec: 'git-credential-osxkeychain' 'get'
trace: run_command: 'git-credential-osxkeychain' 'get'
trace: run_command: 'git credential-osxkeychain store'
trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'git credential-osxkeychain store' 'git credential-osxkeychain store'
trace: exec: 'git-credential-osxkeychain' 'store'
trace: run_command: 'git-credential-osxkeychain' 'store'
```

Comment: When you type in "`git --version`", what do you see?

Comment: it shows 'git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)'

Comment: how about when you try "`git push origin master`" (assuming "`master`" is the branch you are pushing into)?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/12613346/6309 help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16054641/6309? Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13831491/6309?

Comment: @Michael Dautermann 'git push origin master' leads the same result.Moreover another git project has the same problem.

Comment: @VonC stackoverflow.com/a/13831491/6309 is what I need, thanks!!